# Mac App:com.killed app because "its use of apple.developer.aps-environment entitlement is not allowed"

Tags: macos, app-store, distribution

I met a problem when I validated an OSX app before submitting to Mac App Store.
I followed the OS X Workflow Guide (Page 79) to test the  installation.
I paid attention to use the install certificate which appeared under "Identitied without profiles" to create a install package. Then I used installer command to install it:
sudo installer -store -pkg "MyApplication.pkg" -target /
 Finally, the app was installed in the /Application.
However, the app couldn't  launch and the console had log:
"taskgated: killed com.companyname.appbundle  because its use of the com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlement is not allowed"

I'm sure the APNS is enabled for that Apple ID, and I also find a post which has met the same problem in the [forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/732763):

Does any met the problem?

Comment: The same question exists on the Apple Developer Forums with no answer: https://devforums.apple.com/message/732763.  Sounds bad.

Comment: Yes, but the forum is not so active like here.

Comment: Agreed, but questions there normally get some reply from an Apple engineer if there is an easy solution.  The lack of reply there suggests that this is a deep rooted issue that's not easy to solve.